# How to make this grid content section in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

I am developing an eLearning platform and I want to make this type of videos recommendation section that shows videos in two rows grid format that is horizontally scrollable

Comment: can you include that you;ve tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crossAxisCount: 2`,

```dart
GridView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  gridDelegate:
      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
    child: Text("$index"),
  ),
),
```